# modifying elements of getElementsByClass results in NaN

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementsbyclassname

I am running into trouble with this script below, as I take a collection based on a class name and then modify the class names of each member of the collection respectively the programs triggers that the very items of the collection are undefined.

I assume this has to do with the collection falling apart as I remove what made the elements belong to the collection? Could you give me a hint to how I could implement smth like this?

```js
var toggle1 = document.getElementById("toggle1");
toggle1.addEventListener("click", Colortoggle);

function Colortoggle() {
  if (toggle1.className === " white") {
    var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("white");
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      collection[i].className -= "white";
      collection[i].className += "black";
    }
  } else {
    var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("black");
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      collection[i].className -= "black";
      collection[i].className += "white";
    }
  }
  console.log("colortoggle was finished");
}
```

```css
.white {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f5f6f7;
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.black {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle1" class="white">toggle1</div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
```

These are the classes in the beginning:
[image]

This is the change in classes:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The main logic for below code is `toggle1.classList.contains("white")` this statement return true if toggle has class `white` else return false.
- WIth DOM elements you can use this `classList` methods `classList.add()`,`classList.remove()`.
- `classList.add()` => this will add class to selected DOM element.
- `classList.remove()` => this will remove class to selected DOM element.
- for more information abslout classList method please visit [this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
var toggle1 = document.querySelector("#toggle1");
toggle1.addEventListener("click", Colortoggle);

function Colortoggle() {
  if (toggle1.classList.contains("white")) {
    var collection = document.querySelectorAll(".white");
    collection.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.add("black");
      element.classList.remove("white");
    })
  } else {
    var collection = document.querySelectorAll(".black");
    collection.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.add("white");
      element.classList.remove("black");
    })
  }
  console.log("colortoggle was finished");
}
```

```css
.main div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.white {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: black;
}

.black {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="toggle1" class="white">toggle1 click here</div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, the subtraction operator (-) does not work with non-numbers; that is why it yields `NaN`. If you want to edit the class name of an element, please use methods like [add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add), [remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove). For more information, please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Answer (score 3):

As a sidenote: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a **live** HTMLCollection, which means you should never iterate over it using a for-loop **while also modifying elements such as that they get removed from the collection**.

Lets picture this:

Let this be the collection `getElementsByClassName('foo')`, with `->` displaying the current iteration of the loop.

```
// list before iterating
    0: <div class="foo">0</div>
    1: <div class="foo">1</div>
    2: <div class="foo">2</div>

// first iteration i=0
 -> 0: <div class="foo">0</div> // in this iteration, remove .foo
    1: <div class="foo">1</div>
    2: <div class="foo">2</div>

// still first iteration, but now collection[0] is actually what was collection[1] before
 -> 0: <div class="foo">1</div>
    1: <div class="foo">2</div>

// second iteration i=1
    0: <div class="foo">1</div> // we never touch this one!!
 -> 1: <div class="foo">2</div>
```

You will not have this problem if instead of `getElementsByClassName('foo')` you work with `querySelectorAll('.foo')`.

Second sidenote: No, this cannot be fixed using `for (const div of divs)` instead, as it internally seems to work with indexes as well.